# disable all the elements in html

Tags: javascript, html

How can we disable all the elements in html through javascript.The easiest way...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suggest to do it the "Lightbox"-style way.

Add an absolute positioned, transparent, full screen div Layer above the Page.
This way, the user can't even click on a Link.

To give the user a visual feedback that the page is disabled, 
you can make the div e. g. 50% transparent black.

BTW, here is also a [jQuery Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) that uses a similar technique.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if you can get focus to one of the elements behind the div (by tabbing to it or with a keyboard shortcut)

Comment: @Darren - Yep, to properly simulate a modal dialog, you have to trap all keyboard events too, especially Tab keys, to prevent the focus from leaving the dialog element.
You might possibly reset all of the tab-able elements to `tabindex='-1'`, but then you have to reset them all back after the dialog closes.

Answer (score 36):

The easiest way is to put all form elements you want to disable inside a `<fieldset>` and then disable the fieldset itself.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/xdkf9b8j/1/

If you don't want the border around the fieldset, remove it per css.

Comment: Note that on IE, textfields are greyed out, but still editable.

Answer (score 15):

Try this,

```
function disableForm(theform) {
        if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
            for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
            var formElement = theform.elements[i];
                if (true) {
                    formElement.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or else you can try this too, as RaYell said

```
function disableForm() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].disabled = true;
    }
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
        textareas[i].disabled = true;
    }
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

To disable the whole page you can find some info [here](http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2009/02/disable-all-page-elements-with.html),

Comment: I am not so fond of this answer, but the css selector can be hacked like:
`var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, button")`. And then loop like above.

Comment: this is cleaner, thanks Fandi!

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why you would need that but this will work:

```
// this will disable all input elements
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var len = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: don't forget the textareas! :D

Comment: this is just an example, you could do the same with `textarea` and `select`

Comment: But you need to take care of other elements also. Div, span, etc to prevent their events from happening.

Comment: @phoenix> This isn't part of the question, is it?

Comment: Also don't forget the `select` elements

Comment: Is it missing a bracket pair? On `elems[i].disabled`?

Comment: "I don't know why you would need that ... " - I needed to do it

Answer (score 6):

All the form elements (inputs, selects, textareas) within a form, are accesible through the [form.elements HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements),  you can iterate the collection disabling each element:

```
function disableForm(form) {
var length = form.elements.length,
    i;
  for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
    form.elements[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
disableForm(document.forms[0]);
disableForm(document.getElementById('formId'));
```

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious, but the same function (tweaked) can be used to re-enable the form. `function enableForm(form) {var length = form.elements.length,    i;  for (i=0; i < length; i++) { form.elements[i].disabled = false;  }}`

Answer (score 4):

To lock:

```
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll("button, input, select, textarea");
    for (var c of controls) {
        c.disabled = true;
    }
```

To unlock:

```
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll("button, input, select, textarea");
    for (var c of controls) {
        c.disabled = false;
    }
```

That simple.

Answer (score 3):

Once i had to create a tutorial for my website. I needed to disable all interactions on a page excluding some elements. To do so i used this method: 
First make sure to remove all events bindings from your page elements. You can do this by using:

```
   $('*').unbind();
```

Next disable all links on your page:

```
   $('a').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){return false;})});
```

and disable all inputs:

```
   $('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

The code needs to be executed at the end of your document. BTW you may exclude some elements within jquery selector to keep them active.

Comment: or you can run this in the `$(function() {})` DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just and without crutches!

```
/**
 * Enable/disable all form controlls
 * @param status Status: true - form active, false - form unactive
 */
HTMLFormElement.prototype.setStatus = function (status) {
    for (var i in this.elements) {
        this.elements[i].disabled = !status;
    }
};

// Example:
var my_form = document.getElementById('my_form_with_many_inputs');
my_form.setStatus(false); // Disable all inputs in form
my_form.setStatus(true); // Enable all inputs in form
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what result you need you could also do

```
`document.getElementById('main_form').style.display = 'none';`
```

Where `main_form` is the id of your form. You can use the same technique to hide a `div` containing whatever elements you want to disable.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to add a div with highest z-index having width:100% and height:100%.It will cover your entire page and make everything not clickable means disabled virtually.It is best,because it will not use any loop and any complex code.