# How to block a panel's contents but not block the entire page

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a requirement   where    I  have   2    panels.
The  first panel is  having   some  content. The Second  panel is  having   some    content

but here I  need  to  block the Panel1.  This  means  I want even  panel1   to appear  but   it  should  be    blocked  like things  means  when user  clicks on  any button in panel1   Nothing  should  happen inside the panel1.  It  should not   be allowed.   It's  something  like  make the   panel 1  visible  but  blocking all the  contents  inside the Panel1   blocked like things.
 but  any  Functionality in  panel 2  content should  work. like  clicking on the  textbox,  button click,

the  2  panels  appear like  this

panel1: -->  contents  of this  should  be blocked,  but visible

panel2:-->    you can  make  any changes  you need

hope  my Question is Clear

any help  would  be Great 
 Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Give a look to the [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) jQuery plugin, check the [Element Blocking demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element).

Comment: @CMS: This jQuery plugin is specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298034/disable-all-the-elements-in-html, but i haven't checked the element blocking demo. Thanks CMS

Answer (score 1):

Use the technique used by many Lightbox and Modal Dialog plugins: put a semi-transparent div over the top of the area you want to make "disabled". In the case of those plugins, they make it cover the entire page, but in your situation, just position it at the same position as the panel, giving it the same width and height.