# Disable parent window of popup in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page on which when 'Search' button is clicked a popup window is open,

I want to disable parent window on this popup , for which I am using

```
window.opener.document.body.disabled=true;
```

but though it make parent window appear as disabled, it actually dont make it disabled, all controls, links tabs are enabled and can be used/clicked.

What Should I do?

**EDIT** I cannot use Modal for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), and set it as [modal](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html) form. Read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298348/1163607) for more tips.
2. Another option would be iterate through all the `input` and `anchor` in the page and and explicitly set `disabled=true` for each of them.
3. [This blog](http://fczaja.blogspot.in/2009/02/disable-all-page-elements-with.html) describes how to disable all page elements with transparent `div` , using *CSS* and bit of *javascript*.

Comment: thank you for response... I am adapting last method but I want to make parent screen appear grayish(but all of it's content are appearent) so that user knows that it is disabled and cannot be functional until pop up is closed ... something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JxNdT/ ... how can I do that? because in this example all the contents are enclosed with in <div> while according to the blog which you shared I am not enclosing content within div which In my case is working fine... what should I do?.... help much appreciated.