# GeckoFX disable form input while keeping scrollbars

Tags: c#, geckofx, window-handles

The property `Enabled` of a GeckoFX browser determines if the whole browser can get inputs or not.

However, if it's placed as `false` then the scrollbars are being unable to click on or dragged at all.

I'm looking for a way to disable the whole browser without disabling the scrollbars, in simple terms, to disable all the content, prevent them from getting inputs from a form.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of routes: Instead of `geckowebbrowser.Enabled = false;`

1. [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298047/8291949) all `input`, `select`, `textarea`, `button`, and links on the DOM e.g.

   ```
   GeckoElementCollection byTag = _browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
   foreach (var ele in byTag)
   {
       var input = ele as GeckoInputElement;
       input.Disabled = true;
   }
   ```

   etc..
2. remove the pointer events from clickable elements, e.g.

   ```
   var byTag = _browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
   foreach (var ele in byTag)
   {    
        var a = ele as GeckoHtmlElement;
       //a.SetAttribute("disabled", @"true");
       a.SetAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none;cursor: default;");
   }
   ```
3. Use an invisible CSS blocker overlay ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucf57r1p/1/)), e.g. using JavaScript

```js
//UI block
window.onload = function() {        
    var blockUI = document.createElement("div");
    blockUI.setAttribute("id", "blocker");
    blockUI.innerHTML = '<div></div>'
    document.body.appendChild(blockUI);
    
    //unblock it
    //var cover = document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#blocker
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.0;
    background-color: #111;
    z-index: 9000;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="bloc">Blocked UI</button>
```

In the code-behind of my [WPF demo](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/using-the-gecko-web-browser-in-wpf/) app I append the overlay after the page has finished loading in the DocumentCompleted event:

```
using Gecko;
using Gecko.DOM;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Linq;    
namespace GeckoWpf {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
        }    
        void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
             //unsubscribe
            _browser.DocumentCompleted -= browser_DocumentCompleted;

            GeckoElement rt = _browser.Document.CreateElement("div");
            rt.SetAttribute("id", "blocker");
            rt.SetAttribute
            (
            "style",
            "position: fixed;"
            + "top: 0px;"
            + "left: 0px;"
            + "width: 100%;"
            + "height: 100%;"
            + "opacity: 0.0;"
            + "background-color: #111;"
            + "z-index: 9000;"
            + "overflow: auto;"
            );
            _browser.Document.Body.AppendChild(rt);
        }    
        WindowsFormsHost _host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        GeckoWebBrowser _browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();    
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            _browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            _host.Child = _browser;
            GridWeb.Children.Add(_host);    
            _browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

4. Override the `OnClick` event in your main application window or the Gecko Dom Events and set the event to `e.Handled = true;`

There are certainly other options as well.

Comment: None of those suggestions have helped, but I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: In Edge my solution was simple, check the size of the page, change the size of the browser to fit the page, disable the browser, create a panel at your desired size and put the browser in it, use the panel scrollbars.

Comment: However, when changing the gecko browser it slows it, especially in large sizes, try : 2000 x 20000 for example, the browser will freeze.
If I'd find a solution for this it'd be great, or a solution based on window handles.
@wp78de

Comment: also another way would be to resize the browser, draw it to an image, resize it again and show the image in a panel.
the problem is that it'd be very slow, take a lot of cpu, and not be live to the high end.
in edge it was easy, in gecko fx i can't find a suitable solution.

Comment: if the width is 100% so it takes the scrollbars in it too, so it'd disable the scrollbars as well.
therefore, it's not useful.

Comment: @matanjustme the overlay approach works as expected in my WPF sample application. I can scroll like in a regular browser but cannot click or input anything. Do you want me to share my sample?

Comment: share it please then.

Comment: another way : https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/25ls, same problem as well

Comment: i don't program in wpf, so i have no idea how a xaml would help me.
of course if i can use it as an end user, to just change the provided urls to different ones and see if it works there fine as well it'd be good, of course programmatically and not as an executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179951/discussion-between-wp78de-and-matan-justme).